# Left Join performance is too slow when query more then 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 7 tables which I need to query, every table have `district_id` (district has it's own id as id and it's auto increment field).

Table names are :

```
districts, blocks, panchayats, habitations, villages, divisions, sub_divisions
```

Here's the query syntax i use for test.

```
SELECT 
d.id, d.district_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS total_block, 
COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS gp_total,
COUNT(DISTINCT v.id) AS vi_total,
COUNT(DISTINCT h.id) AS h_total
FROM districts d 
LEFT JOIN blocks b ON b.district_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN panchayats g ON g.district_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN villages v ON v.district_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN habitations h ON h.district_id = d.id
GROUP BY district_name
```

It works fine till 3 Left Join but when it comes to the fourth it run the query but never stop.

**Objective**: I try to parse all the districts and fetch count data of all the matching `district_id` from blocks, panchayats, habitations, villages, divisions and sub_divisions.

**Expect result**:

```
districts | blocks | panchayats | habitations | villages | division | sub_divisions
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC       | 6      | 20         | 10          | 10       | 3         | 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEF       | 3      | 12         | 4           | 7        | 7         | 4
```

I am not very good with SQL, thank you in advance for your time and help.

Table Structures:

```
Districts
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | district_name | district_code | last_update(TIMESTAMP) | created_on(DATE)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Blocks 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | block_name | block_code | district_id | last_update | created_on
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Panchayats
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | panchayat_name | panchayat_code | district_id | block_id | last_update | created_on
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Habitations 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |  name  |  code  |  district_id  |  block_id  |  panchayat_id | village_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Villages
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id |  village_name  |  village_code  |  district_id  |  block_id | panchayat_id 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Division
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | name | district_id .....
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub Division
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | name | district_id
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All the ID are Primary Keys, on `phpMyAdmin` I make `district_id` in every table index.

Comment: Are the tables properly indexed?

Comment: How many rows in each table?

Comment: Is LEFT JOIN mandatory here or could you only use INNER JOIN ?

Comment: did you tried to only do a left join with the 4th table..

Comment: @Ksven i have to use LEFT JOIN because i have to parse all the district data even if there are no match data at the right table.
i am good to use other suggestion if you have a good one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query as you have it, will potentially create a huge result set, and then apply 4 different distinct counts on that result set. In this case, you might be better off using subqueries. Admittedly, also not a great solution...

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.district_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(b.id) FROM blocks b WHERE b.district_id = d.id) total_block,
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM panchayats p WHERE p.district_id = d.id) gp_total,
    (SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM villages v WHERE v.district_id = d.id) vi_total,
    (SELECT COUNT(h.id) FROM habitations h WHERE h.district_id = d.id) h_total
FROM districts d
```

Comment: That works perfectly, extremely fast too, not even a sec to query more then 800 records. Is there a way that i can also use search term like WHERE clause in it - like WHERE blocks.block_name = 'ABC'.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. Just have to stay aware of what you're actually querying.

Comment: where do i have to use where clause?

SELECT
  ........
FROM districts d
WHERE blocks.block_name = 'abc' 
?

Comment: It depends where you want the condition to be applied. If you want to limit the counts in some way, you have to add it to the relevant subquery. If you want to limit the districts in some way, you need to add it to the main query.

Comment: Been struggling with this for 2 days, Thank You Very Much Robby

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
GROUP BY d.id, d.district_name
```

in your original query?

I think MySQL permits to write `GROUP BY` in a way you did but other databases wouldn'let you write it this way.